solution-verification | Under what conditions is $AMC'N$ square?
the problem
Let the rectangular parallelepiped $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ in which $AB=a, BC=b, AA'=c$.  A plane passing through the points $A, C'$ intersects the edges $BB'$ in $M$ and $DD'$ in $N$.  Under what conditions is $AMC'N$ square?
my solution
the drawing

As you can see I noted $B'M=x=> MB=c-x$
$AMC'N$ is a square <=> $AM=C'N$ and $AN=MC'$ and $\angle AMC'=90$ and $MC'=AM$
by  $AM=C'N$ and $AN=MC'$ and the fact that $AD=BC, D'C'=AB$ we can show using the thorem of pytagora that $AM=C'N$ and $AN=MC'$<=> $D'N=c-x, ND=x$
$\angle AMC'=90$ <=> $AM^2+MC'^2=AC'^2$ <=> $2x^2-2cx=0 <=> 2x(x-c)=0 <=> x=0$ or $x=c$
if $x=0$ then $M=B', N=D$ and if $x=c$ then $M=B, N=D'$
$MC'=AM <=> (c-x)^2+a^2=b^2+x^2 <=> c^2-2cx+a^2=b^2$
above we showed that $\angle AMC'=90 <=> x=0$  or  $x=c$ and  AMC'N is a square <=> $AM=C'N$ and $AN=MC'$ and $\angle AMC'=90$ and $MC'=AM$ so we can say that
$c^2-2cx+a^2=b^2$ can have 2 possibilities: if $x=0$ then $M=B', N=D$=> $c^2+a^2=b^2 <=> AB'=AD$
and if $x=c$ then $M=B, N=D'=> a^2=b^+c^2=> BC'=AB$
so AMC'N is a square <=> if $M=B'$, $N=D$ and $c^2+a^2=b^2$ or if $M=B, N=D'$ and $a^2=b^2+c^2$
As you can see I put this as a solution-verification because I'm not sure of the part where I take those cases, I felt like I didn't explain well and that my idea isn't well structured.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

just take the sphere centered at the midpoint of $AC'$ that passes through $A$. The candidates for the vertices of your square will be the meeting of this sphere with the sides of the parallelepiped

@hellofriends Thanks for your idea, but i don't really understand what you want to say! Can you be more explicit or look at my idea and tell me if it is right?

your theorem of Pythagoras was wrong, it should have been $AC'^2 = AM^2+MC'^2$

@hellofriends ooo...sorry... i edited it... now is my idea correct?

almost, you imposed that $\angle AMC' = 90^{\circ}$ and got the correct conclusion that either $x=0$ or $x=c$ but this alone doesn't mean that $AMC'N$ is a square, you in fact, can't usually have a square.

@hellofriends I dont understand what do you mean... i also put the condition for 2 adjacent sides must be congruent...those $a^2=b^2+c^2$ and $b^2=c^2+a^2$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your reasoning is correct: points $AB'C'D$ lie on the same plane, as well as $ABC'D'$.

Let's suppose that there is such $M$ in the middle of $BB'$ such that $AMC'N$ is a square.
It is well known that, in space, the locus of the points who see a segment $XY$ under a right angle, i.e. $\angle AXB = 90^{\circ}$, is a sphere of diameter $XY$. This is a trivial generalization of Thales' theorem.
By this fact, we know that $\angle AMC' = 90^{\circ} \implies M$ is on the sphere of diameter $AC'$.
It is not hard to see that a sphere meets a line in at most two points. But let me show you that the above sphere then must meet line $BB'$ on the points $B$ and $B'$.
We know that the line $C'B'$ is perpendicular to the plane $(AA'BB')$ as $C'B' \perp A'B'$ and $C'B' \perp BB'$. But when a line is perpendicular to two meeting lines of a plane, it means that this line is perpendicular to any line of the plane, therefore, $C'B' \perp AB' \implies \angle AB'C' = 90^{\circ} \implies B'$ is on our sphere.
Very similarly: $AB \perp BC, AB \perp BB' \implies AB \perp (BCC') \implies AB \perp C'B \implies B$ is on our sphere.
Conclusion: if there was a point $M \in BB'$ such that $\angle AMC' = 90^{\circ}$, we would have our sphere of diameter $AC'$ meeting the line $BB'$ in three distinct points. No square or rectangle can be constructed on the way you want to.
